# Two Table Query Slow: File Sort Problem

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query the latest entries on two different tables as one query:

```
SELECT
    news.title AS news_title,
    news.sid AS news_id,
    downloads.lid AS download_id,
    downloads.title AS download_title
FROM
    news,
    downloads
ORDER BY
    news_id DESC,
    download_id DESC
    LIMIT 0,10
```

The query is really slow and it says `"Using temporary; Using filesort"` when I do an `EXPLAIN`. Each table has about 2,000 items. Each table's primary key Index is the id (`lid` and `sid`).

Answer (score 2):

You have no join condition so it's joining every row in news with every row in downloads. This is called a cross join or cartesian product. So if news has 1000 rows and downloads has 3000 rows you will get 3 million rows returned.

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT news.title AS news_title,
       news.sid AS news_id,
       downloads.lid AS download_id,
       downloads.title AS download_title
FROM news n
JOIN downloads d ON n.some_column = d.join_column /* fill this part in */
ORDER BY news_id DESC,download_id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

In all likelihood one join column will be a primary key of one column and a foreign key in the other.

Oh, make sure the foreign key is indexed too.

Comment: And that is why you use `inner join` instead of just a comma when joining tables. The former forces a join condition.

Comment: Or you could, on the other hand, know what you're doing, @Eric :-) And, @cletus is right, at 2000 rows each that's four million rows to sort before grabbing the first 10.

Comment: @Pax: Anything I can do to protect me from me is a winner in my book.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to join the tables.  What you have done is created a query that spits out a Cartesian product - every row from one table and every row from the other.  That's why it's slow.

You want to add a WHERE table A.key = table b.field to join them.

Lance